# How to run Firebase Firestore Cloud Functions locally and debuging it, with WebStorm and Ngrok?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It's Known that you have to test your functions first, before deploying them to firebase to avoid loops and unwanted behavior. I need to run a local environment to test it first, How can I do that?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question shows no research was done before asking - the answer is clearly in the documentation.

Comment: maybe I forgot to say, is with Webstorm and tunneling with Ngrok, I couldn't find any documentation or tutorial about this, the firebase doc is using VisualCode not Webstorm.

Answer (score 0):

//How to Debug Firebase Functions locally

1 - Start EMU for debugging functions(required Java installed)
firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions

2 - Connect Webstorm Debugger
Edit Run/Debug configurations -> Attach to Node/Chrome (select the correct port(just in case))(9229 by default)

3 - Run ngrok and server the functions port
(http://127.0.0.1:5001/your-firebase-app)
|         here       |
./ngrok http 127.0.0.1:5001

4 - Finish output

|ngrok tunnel| |rest of your API endpoints|

http://4386-2600-8801-192-4500-4dcd-e70f-e09f-63cb.ngrok.io/wherever-you-app-is/app